# Numerical solution of an integral equation

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, integral-equations

I have problems with a solution of an integral equation in MATLAB: all conditions are double-checked, but the answer is incorrect. Let me state the equation:
$$
x(s) = g(s)+\int\limits_0^1x(t)f(t-s)\,dt\quad(1)
$$
where 
$$
f(t) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi(1+(t+1)^4)}
$$
and 
$$
g(s) = \int\limits_{1-s}^\infty f(t)\,dt.
$$
For the solution $x$ I know that it should be bounded $0\leq x(s)\leq 1$ and monotonically increasing. To solve this equation I used [fie](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19456-fredholm-integral-equations) toolbox which is also supported by many publications of K. Atkinson and provides strict bounds on the error. The graph of the solution:
[image: fie]

Note an ugly jump close to $0$ as well as non-monotonic behavior of the function. An error said to be less than $10^{-4}$.

This result didn't satisfied me and I then found $x$ with a naive approach: made a grid on $[0,1]$ with a step $10^{-3}$ and replaced $x(s)$ by $x_i = x(s_i)$, $g(s)$ by $g_i = g(s_i)$, $f(t-s)$ by $f_{ij} = f(s_j-s_i)$ and integral by a sum. As a result I obtained $(\mathbf I - \delta \mathbf f)\mathbf w = \mathbf g$. Solution of this system is on this picture. With this method an error is less than $0.01$.

[image: Naive solution]

I used *fie* toolbox for the problem which is much tough and the result was perfect, but for the current equation something goes wrong. I hope that it's due to the fact I've encoded something incorrect.

I spent already three days trying to find a mistake - but there is no so much code and I wonder if you can help me. Maybe, it will be better if I put the code here for someone to help me check it? In the case this question is off-top, I am sorry - just tell me, I'll delete it.

P.S. Mathematica is able to give an explicit form for $g$, so I can put it here if it helps.

**Edited:** Added Code.
I use the following procedure to call *fie*

```
[soln,errest,cond] = Fie(1,0,1,1,@kPdfNew,@rhsNew)
```

First numbers are $\lambda  =1$, $a = 0$, $b = 1$ and behavior $=1$ - smooth.
For the function $g$ I use

```
function output = rhsNew(x)
n = length(x);
output = x;
for i=1:n
        output(i) = quad(@Poi,1-x(i),100);
end
```

and for the kernel I put

```
function output = kPdfNew(s,t)
z = t-s; 
n = length(z);
output = z;
for i = 1:n
    output(i) = Poi(z(i));
end
```

where Poi is a density $f(t)$ given by

```
function output = Poi(z)
n = length(z);
output = z;
for i=1:n
    output(i) = sqrt(2)/pi/(1+(z(i)+1)^4);
end
```

You may comment on the integration till $100$ rather then $\infty$ - but first, the difference $\int\limits_{100}^\infty f(t)\,dt$ is smaller then a machine precision and second, before I used the explicit form for $g$ and the result was the same.

Comment: Yes, including the code would be a good idea. If it's too long, there's [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: I think you might have had more answers asking this on http://stackoverflow.com (you might want to consider flagging a mod to migrate this question, though it is not off-topic here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in the case someone will have the same problem, here is the answer. The problem was in working with vector-argument, vector-value functions in MATLAB, so the kernel should be given in a slightly different way:

```
function output = kPdfNew(s,t)
z = t-s; 
[nx,ny] = size(s);
output = zeros(size(s));
    for ii = 1:nx
      for jj = 1:ny
        output(ii,jj) = sqrt(2)/pi/(1+(z(ii,jj)+1)^4);
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case performance and readability are issues, you can achieve what [your answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56868/163) did with the following code as well:

```
function output = kPdfNew(s,t)
output = sqrt(2)/pi./(1+(t-s+1).^4);
end
```

(The main problem with your original code was that you iterated `for i=1:length(z)`, instead of `length` you could have used [numel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/numel.html))